# Unable to use set_time_limit()

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I can't extend the execution time in PHP5.6

Consider the next snippet

```
var_dump(ini_get('max_execution_time'));
var_dump(ini_set('max_execution_time', '600'));
var_dump(ini_set('display_errors', '1'));
var_dump(set_time_limit(0));
die;
```

The response is

```
string(3) "360" 
bool(false) 
string(1) "0" 
bool(false)
```

A few notes
- i don't have suhosin extension
- changing the value in htaccess or vhost does not change the defined value in php.ini
- safe_mode was removed in version 5.4
- i already considered changing the value in php.ini and this is not a solution for my use case.
- i need to run this with apache (not CLI)

Thanks

Comment: Do you have root access?  That's essential to know to consider the best available options.

Comment: Note that `ini_set()` returns the last value so it doesn't tell us whether it actually changed it or not and if it will respect it.  Run a timed test to check it.

Comment: @Julie - read the documentation for ini_set() more carefully. The script execution expires. I don't have root access.i need to change this from php script

Comment: Right, it is refused.  So do you have root access or not?

Comment: @Julie - as I already wrote above, I do NOT have root acces.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was running wamp version 3.0 (windows) with php5.6.15.
Change WAMP to XAMP3.2 (still php5.6.15). It's working for me now.

Thank you for your help